# How to show content of files in 'index' and 'tip of current branch'?

Tags: git

I am new to Git. Basically, when I am working on a branch, there are 3 places I need to consider.

If I can know below things, many concepts will become clear.

1. File *content* in the index (not just file entries).
2. File *content* at the tip of current branch.
3. File *content* in my working tree.

I can easily check 3 within file system.

How to check 1 and 2?

Or at least diff among 1, 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1):

Checking diff among them is easier:

`git diff` shows diff of 1 and 3.

`git diff --cached` shows diff of 2 and 1.

`git diff HEAD` for diff of 2 and 3.

Not a complete solution but `cat 2` should be able to done with some shell trick (implement `git find-object-in-head` and then `git cat-file` it).

Comment: Thx. I guess in a DETACHED HEAD scenario, the `git diff HEAD` will show the diff between `wherever the HEAD is pointing at` and `the working tree`. I will try it.

Comment: I prefer the spelling `git diff --staged`, it's more indicative.

Answer (score 1):

> If I can know below things, many concepts will become clear.
>
> 1. File content in the index (not just file entries).

The index *does not* contain any file *contents.*

You can see what is in the index with `git ls-files`; use `--stage` to get the most complete information.  Note that what is in the index is actually just the hashes, plus stage number, mode, and less interesting items that `ls-files` omits (internal timestamp and other cache information):

```
100644 3ccb06a84f29b059df24a6c579d3be262bd33167 0   .gitignore
[snip]
```

To see the contents, you must use the hash, which is Git's content identifier.  Using `git cat-file -p` you can pretty-print any Git object, including the "blob" objects that hold the files' data:

```
$ git cat-file -p 3ccb06a84f29b059df24a6c579d3be262bd33167
# Object files
*.o
[snip]
```

> File content at the tip of current branch.

The current commit is known as `HEAD`.

As implemented today, `HEAD` is an actual file, so:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

In this case, `HEAD` tells us (and Git) that we are "on a branch", as `git status` puts it.  The name of that branch is `master`.  We know this because `HEAD` is a symbolic reference—its contents start with the literal string `ref:` , including the space—and the rest of its contents are `refs/heads/master` which is the name of a reference in the `refs/heads/` namespace, which is where branch names reside.

As a rule, the way to find out whether you are on a branch is to use `git symbolic-ref HEAD`.  If you are not on a branch, you must be on the special anonymous branch, which Git refers to as a "detached HEAD".

Meanwhile, the ID of the tip commit of branch `master` is stored in one or more files, and can be found using the `git rev-parse` command, which locates the *correct* file.  (If you are willing to get a potentially wrong answer, you can look in `.git/packed-refs` and `.git/refs/heads/master`, which are currently the two applicable files for a branch named `master`.  But it's better to run `git rev-parse`.)

```
$ git rev-parse master
708de7734417df0f6ec44e8b06d8ce566f08f191
```

This is the ID of a commit; again, `git cat-file -p` will pretty-print it:

```
$ git cat-file -p master
tree 624403f4492cd5cbd3c0ab75059ea0229a45d908
[snip]
```

If `HEAD` is detached, the `HEAD` file will contain the raw ID of the commit.  For instance, if I detach `HEAD` from `master`, `.git/HEAD` will contain `708de7734417df0f6ec44e8b06d8ce566f08f191`.

> File content in my working tree.

This is everything you see with your normal command-line utilities, except for the contents of `.git`, which contains Git's repository.  For instance, in a Unix-like shell, you might run `ls -R` to view the file names.  The files' contents are obtained by opening and reading the files as usual.